# Formview: How to set parameter for non-updated items

Tags: c#, webforms, formview

This is probably quite simple but I have not found anything in my readings.  I am trying to update some records however the fields that I do not update are reverting to null and not the `Bind()` value. Because of that my update script is failing. What am I missing?

Here is the `<EditTemplate>`

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                        <h2 class="col-md-12"><asp:Label ID="lbldocid" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("docid") %> /> - <asp:Label ID="lblclient" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("sName") %> /></h2>

                                <div class="left col-md-10"> 
                                    <legend>Matter Info:</legend>
                                       <div class="form-group"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Matter" AssociatedControlID="dcname"/>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="dcname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sDocname") %> /></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-10">
                                    <hr />
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Notes/Comments" AssociatedControlID="dcnotes" /><br />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="dcnotes" runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" Text=<%# Bind("sdocdesc") %> />
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 txsmall"> 
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Filed: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblfiledate" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtFiledate") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Modified: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblmodify" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtLastModified") + " - " + Bind("susermodified") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true"/>                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear-fix col-md-12">
                                   <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" Enabled="false" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" />&nbsp;
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

SQLDATASOURCE Updateparameters:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="DOCID" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="hClient" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="sDocName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="sDocDesc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="sUserModified" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0"></asp:Parameter>
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the types to `SqlDBType` and that appears to have fixed the issue.